# Laravel: Eloquent Eager loading with custom query

Tags: php, laravel

I would like to eager load the following piece of code.

```
  return DB::table('container_slots')
->where('occupied', false)
->join('plate_containers','container_slots.plate_container_id', '=', 'plate_containers.id')
->select('plate_containers.name AS Container', DB::raw('count(container_slots.slot) as no_of_slots'))
->groupBy('plate_container_id')->get();
```

Upon calling the index method.

```
  public function index()
{
    $plateContainers = PlateContainer::with('equipmentStatusCode','storageLocation','plateContainerType')->paginate(10)->toArray();

    return response()->success($plateContainers);
}
```

What is the best way to do so?

I thought I might do something like this.

**PlateContainer Model**

```
  public function slotsCount()
{
  return $this->containerSlots()
  ->where('occupied', false)
  ->join('plate_containers','container_slots.plate_container_id', '=', 'plate_containers.id')
  ->select('plate_containers.name AS Container', DB::raw('count(container_slots.slot) as no_of_slots'))
  ->groupBy('plate_container_id');
}

public function getSlotsCountAttribute()
{
    $this->load('slotsCount');

    $related = $this->getRelation('slotsCount');

    return $related;
}
```

But this returns

> "message": "Method addEagerConstraints does not exist.",

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are calling the wrong relation when you do:

```
$this->load('slotsCount');
```

'slotsCount()' is just a method which does not have the 'addEagerConstraints()' method.

The real relation is 'containerSlots' as I can guess from the code.

After some testing in an analogous situation, I think the sollution could be:

```
public function getSlotsCountAttribute()
{
    $this->load('containerSlots');
    return $this->slotsCount();
}
```

So the call to 'getSlotsCountAttribute()', first eagers load the relation, then returns the count.

Comment: This is returning an empty array `  "get_slots_count_attribute": [] `

Comment: An empty result set is a valid result depending on the data. Is the query in 'slotsCount()' actually retrieving info? I would check the query is doing its job first.

Comment: 'slotsCount()' is not returning anything. I checked the query multiples times else where and it just works.

Comment: Well, then I don't have more ideas. I did check my response in a similar scenario, got the same error but could solve it as mentioned. This is as far as I can get. Sorry mate.